# Inequality Problem with 3 variables.

Tags: inequality

$$(x+y+z)^3\ge27xyz$$

$x,y, z\in R^+_0$

I solved it to $x+y+z$ is greater or equal to 3. thierd root of (x.y.z). i don't know what to do after that.

Comment: Are you supposed to prove this inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is clear by AM-GM, namely $\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$ for $a,b,c\geq 0$

Comment: can you elaborate as i dont know what AM-GM. also didnt understand your solution.

Comment: The inequality of the arithmetic and geometric means. Look it up!

Answer (score 3):

If you have to prove that, note the factorization
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)\cdot \frac12\left((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \right) \ge 0$$
if $a+b+c \ge 0$.  This gives AM-GM inequality for $3$ positive variables, viz. $\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}3 \ge abc$.

Now use $x=a^3, y=b^3, z=c^3$ and cube to get your inequality.